# Macro To Change & Operator Concatenated Formula to =CONCATENATE(a,b,c)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a function that will change a cell that has concatenated elements using the & symbol into one using the `CONCATENATE()` function. So, as an example, I'd want a cell with the `function ="There are "&7&" cats"` to be replaced with `=CONCATENATE("There are ",7," cats")`.

I've got a skeleton of the code I want to write, but I'm having trouble actually making it work. I thought that this would be a fun project to let me try my hand at VBA, but I'm quickly realizing that even after attempting all the Google-fu in the world that I'm still stuck trying to write this code.

So far I've got the following:

```
Function fixConcatenate()
'For each cell in range, replace function elements to swap from & operator concatenation to CONCATENATE() function

    For Each c In ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Cells
    'Insert "=CONCATENATE(" by replacing existing "="
    Range.Replace("=","=CONCATENATE(")

        'If "&" exists inside string, ignore it
        'Else replace "&" with ","
        'End function in cell with ")"

    Next
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression to replace all the ampersand by a "CONCATENATE" formula:

```
Sub UsageExample()

  ReplaceAmpersandByConcat ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

End Sub

Sub ReplaceAmpersandByConcat(target As Range)
  Dim re As Object, cl As Range, str As String

  ' create the regex object
  Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  re.pattern = "(""[^""]*""|[^&]+)(\s*&\s*)"
  re.Global = True

  ' replace each ampersand concatenation with a formula
  For Each cl In target.Cells
    str = cl.formula
    ' if starts with "=" and contains "&" and not "=CONCATENATE"
    If InStrRev(str, "=", 1) = 1 And InStr(str, "&") > 0 And InStr(str, "=CONCATENATE") = 0 Then
      ' replace the ampersand characters
      cl.formula = "=CONCATENATE(" & re.replace(Mid$(str, 2), "$1,") & ")"
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Note that it will not convert the ampersands in a text (ex: A1 & "D&B") and it will skip the cells that have already been converted.

Comment: Works like a charm! I just wish I knew where to begin on writing something like this. I can't say I've ever heard of a regex before, but I'll certainly be reading about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following to use the following code in order to accomplish your goal. The key here is to access the formula itself which is stored in the "c" variable constructed in the for each loop. Secondly you need to replace the components of that formula with the concatenation. Thirdly, I got around the "if statement" by adding a specific phrase [Quote Start] and [Quote End] to indicate if the "&" symbol should be replaced or was in fact a legitimate string component.

```
Function fixConcatenate()
'For each cell in range, replace function elements to swap from & operator concatenation to CONCATENATE() function

For Each c In ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Cells
string_Update = c.Formula
Count = Len(string_Update) - Len(Replace(string_Update, """", ""))
For i = 1 To Count
If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
string_Update = Replace(string_Update, """", "[Quote End]", , i)
Else
string_Update = Replace(string_Update, """", "[Quote Start]", , i)
End If
Next i

string_Update = Replace(string_Update, "=", "=CONCATENATE(")
string_Update = Replace(string_Update, "[Quote End]&", """,")
string_Update = Replace(string_Update, "&[Quote Start]", ",""")
string_Update = Replace(string_Update, "[Quote Start]", ",""")
string_Update = Replace(string_Update, "[Quote End]", """,")
string_Update = string_Update + ")"
c.Formula = string_Update
Next
End Function
```

Comment: You are heading down a rabbit hole here.  Consider what this does to `="A"""&"A"` wich returns `A"A` (results in `=CONCATENATE(,"A",",,","A,")` which returns `A,,A,`)

Comment: You are absolutely correct here and this would need to be addressed if Quotations are to be accounted for in this.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code for your requirement

```
Sub test1()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim t1 As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set Rng = ws.UsedRange



'Looping each cell

For Each c In Rng

    t1 = c.Formula
    Length = Len(c)

    For i = 1 To Length
       ' Changing to concatenate formula
        'Debug.Print Mid(t1, i, 1)
        If Mid(t1, i, 1) = "&" Then
            If Mid(t1, i - 1, 1) = """" Then
                t2 = Replace(t1, "&", ",")
                t3 = Replace(t2, "=", "=concatenate(")
                t3 = t3 & ")"
                c.Formula = t3
            End If
        End If
    Next

Next

End Function
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a VALUE error when I try using the function. Is there something I'm missing here. I'm really interested in seeing how this works as a function vs a sub so thanks for your input! I'll definitely be breaking this down to try and learn from it.

Comment: I am not sure how you are passing value to a function. Could you please let me know. It is working fine for me